# Im getting duplicated response headers using ASP.net and react js running on IIS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

I'm getting this error on my web app using REACT JS AND ASP .NET Core C#

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin. (ministries, line 0)
```

[please check img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsY1x.png)

I didn't get the problem:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy.WithOrigins("http://www.tesvikrotasi.com.tr",
    "http://tesvikrotasi.com.tr")
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
));
```

I'm running Reactjs and Asp.net apps on IIS windows server